# AJAX call to rest service to post the data from HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, post

```
<html>

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <label>username</lable>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
            <label>emailid</lable>
                <input id="emailid" name="emailid" type="text">
                <button id="enter" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var emailId = $("#emailid").val();
            $($enter).click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ".....rest service url....",
                    dataType: JSON,
                    data: {
                        "UserName": userName,
                        "EmailId": emailId
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("error" + e)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to post the form field in rest service which expects a JSON response.
I'm getting an alert error message (object Object)

I'm not getting where the error is.

Comment: Object Object is not an error, its just telling the type of the data your passing to alert()

Comment: but it is not posting the data in to the service

Comment: replace alert("error"+e) with alert(e.Message) so that we know whats the actual error message is when failed

Comment: there is no .Message method to call !!

Comment: there is, its a property of the e (error) object :)

Comment: it doesnt alert anything ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try $.post instead of $.ajax

```
$.post( "your url",{ UserName: userName, EmailId: emailId }, function( data ){
alert("Success");
});
```

Just make sure that parameters you are passing matches with your REST service.

Comment: Is your REST service returning data as expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
$($enter).click(function () {
```

this part of code looks invalid, provide a correct selector to the click function.

Answer (score 0):

First change this
 `$($enter).click(function to
 $("#enter").click(function () {`
Are you sure the the service you written for this task is a post  service...some times i do the mistake like post data and write service for getting data.If you can show your service structure it will help to have a better insight.